# Spring Webflux - Actuator - Netty thread metrics?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

Small question regarding Netty metrics for a Spring Webflux + actuator project please.

In the Spring MVC world, combined with actuator, we have metrics such as:

```
tomcat_threads_busy_threads
tomcat_threads_current_threads
tomcat_threads_config_max_threads

jetty_threads_busy
jetty_threads_current
jetty_threads_config_max
```

Which helps a lot to get the overall status of the application.

However, in Webflux, it seems there is no equivalent.

I was expecting something like `netty_threads_busy` or something equivalent, but could not find anything related.

May I ask what would be the equivalent in Netty Webflux world please?

Thank you

Comment: Another good thing to enable is `Schedulers.enableMetrics()` in your main method before starting the spring boot app.

Comment: Learned something new here, and the metrics are very helpful (upvote)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metrics expose by reactor-netty are not enabled by default in spring boot. There was a previous discussion on this [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19388) and the decision was not to enable these by default.

If you wanted to enable the netty server metrics in your own application, you can add the following bean to customise the Netty HttpServer.

```
    @Bean
    public NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer(){
        return httpServer -> httpServer.metrics(true, uriMappingFunction);
    }
```

**Caveat**:

If you have path parameters in any of your URIs you should provide a `uriMappingFunction` that converts them to templated URIs ie. `/user/1` -> `/user/{id}`. Failure to do so could lead to cardinality explosion in your MeterRegistry.

Enabling this feature also comes with the following recommendation:

> It is strongly recommended applications to configure an upper limit for the number of the URI tags.

[Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics)

[Java Doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/index.html?reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.html)

Comment: Learned something new, many thanks :)

Just follow up question, httpServer.metrics(true); is protected. There are three other .metrics taking arguments. Do you know where I can find the documents, or do you know how to use them please?

Comment: I've added links to the reference documentation and the java documentation that will hopefully answer your questions. If not let me know

Comment: sorry, I must be on a slightly older version of reactor-netty when that `metrics(boolean)` method was public

Comment: provided further clarification on why you should implement a `uriMappingFunction` and the potential consequences if you do not.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanations. If I may ask, what would be the ```uriMappingFunction``` in this case? In my app, I expose the endpoints from the ```/actuator/prometheus``` route. Meaning I should build a ```uriMappingFunction``` mapping to my prometheus endpoint?

Comment: the linked javadoc explains the purpose of that parameter

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think I made it work, It does answers half of the question (upvote!), since I do see netty metrics, but nothing related to netty_threads

Comment: reactor-netty doesn't produce metrics related to http server threads as the threading model is very different. There is a good explanation on this github issue about - https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1366

Comment: Are there any sample code of `uriMappingFunction`?

Comment: I have written as a follows: ```private fun uriTagSupplier(url: String): String {
        return when {
            url.contains("a") -> A_URL
            url.contains("b") -> B_URL
            else -> "DEFAULT"
        }
    }```